# How do Instagram Follower providers work with no password required?

Tags: python, instagram, instagram-api

There are many services that give you real Instagram followers and they don't need to have your password.
I am trying to build a similar service with python but first I need to figure out 2 questions:

1. What is their approach that you don't follow people but you get real followers?
2. How can they provide you the service when they don't even need your password?

Comment: I'm confused why you think a follower needs your password.

Comment: I am talking about the company that brings you followers. They just ask for your username and you purchase a package and they bring few hundreds of followers to you.
For example: 
https://www.ista-labs.com/instagram_auto_likes_views.html

Comment: Followers don't need your password, so why would the company need it?  They're just organizing a bunch of people to click on your "follow me" link, right?

Comment: Of course, followers don't need your password. why would they?
Those companies get your username and everythey you will get for example 500 to 1500 followers based on the package you purchase.
My questions is how they get you followers with just your username. without a need for your to like bunch of posts so they like you back or follow you.

Comment: I assume the company is paying those 500 people a few cents each to click on your follow link, or perhaps they're just bot accounts and not even real people.

Comment: @JohnGordon It's almost certainly the latter.